# kubernetes client go watch a resource only one time

Tags: go, kubernetes, client

I have a concept in my application to delete a JOB and then just recreated it.
I have tried to delete the Job, then just sleep for a while and try to recreate it.

but I´m not convinced with this solution it´s not optimistic.

So, After something happened, from my code I will Run a function in a Goroutine.

here's the code inside the function.

```
func CreateGenerateJob() {
    err = clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Delete(jobName, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("could not delete job: %v", err)
    }

    time.Sleep(60*time.Second)

    createdJob, err :=  clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Create(job)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("could not create job: %v", err)
    }

}
```

This is not Good at all.
But, I had the idea to watch for the deleted resources.

So I added a watch function before deleting the Job,

```
func CreateGenerateJob() {

    watchForTheJob(clientset)

    err = clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Delete(jobName, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("could not delete job: %v", err)
    }

}
```

The content of the function is as follows:

```
func watchForTheJob(clientset kubernetes.Interface) {
    kubeInformerFactory := kubeinformers.NewSharedInformerFactory(clientset, time.Second*30)
    svcInformer := kubeInformerFactory.Batch().V1().Jobs().Informer()

    svcInformer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
        DeleteFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
            logrus.Infof("service deleted: %s \n", obj)
            // Now I can create the Job.
            createdJob, err :=  clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Create(job)
            if err != nil {
              logrus.Fatalf("could not create job: %v", err)
            }
            logrus.Infof("job created: %s", createdJob.Name)
        },
    },)

    stop := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(stop)
    kubeInformerFactory.Start(stop)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I´m not sure if the JOB is really available or not. (can the delete happens or not)

Since I´m running the Whole code of this package in a goroutine.

```
go adapter.CreateGenerateJob()
```

I would like to exit the Goroutine after successfully the job created, no matter if the job is deleted -> then recreated or just created only.

it might be a solution if on watching for the job, then after creating it, just exit the watch event.

Any, solution for that.

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: The goal is simple: delete a job if it exists and create the Job.

Comment: But like is this for a simple script runner?

Comment: it's a controller running inside the cluster.

Comment: Yes but what is the actual human facing end goal.

Comment: I want the watch event exists after the creation of the job is done.